# Insert Unicode string to DB using Linq

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, unicode, hebrew

When I try to excecute this:

```
INSERT INTO [DB_NAME].[dbo].[Table]
([Column])
VALUES('some_hebrew_characters')
```

I get only questions mark in the column. If I change it to  N'some_hebrew_characters' - then it's OK. Why is this happening? How can I translate it to Linq?

How can I make this table to treat all data as Unicode by default? My colum collation is Hebrew_CS_AI, and server is SQL 2008 R2.

Thanks!

---EDIT----

something I just noticed:
even if I run this

```
SELECT 'some_hebrew_characters'
```

Im getting questions mark in my results grid

Comment: What is your column type? Nvarchar or varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to mark your column as NVARCHAR also?

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's your editor's default enncoding is not unicode.

To be sure, save your query as a unicode file in SQL SERVER Management Studio and re-run it.

I think if you get results through Linq there would be right.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prefix the '' with the letter N

when inserting a value that contains unicode characters, you need to do this:

```
 insert into table_name(unicode_field) values (N'会意字')
```

without the N prefix, they'll be passed as ASCII characters.

Also, be sure that the column you're inserting to, supports unicode characters - i.e. nchar, nvarchar, ntext.